# How to prioritize network connections?

Tags: networking, internet, 14.10

Is it possible to prioritize network connections? I don't want to connect to WiFi when wired connection is available.

Comment: this may help: http://askubuntu.com/a/239639/294611

Answer (score 4):

[image: network manager ubuntu]

- open System Settings > Network
- now click on Wired network > Options
- A small window will open. now choose **IPv4 Settings** tab
- search for **Routes** button
- now check **Use this connection only for resources on its network**
- now restart your network manager to get the settings to work. `sudo service network-manager restart`