# directing ssh to use wireless instead of wired network

Tags: 14.04, wireless, ssh

I have both wired and wireless network on my laptop. I want to ssh a server that is accessible over the wireless network only. How can I direct ssh to use WiFi for connection to server without having to remove the wired network?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/239624/how-to-prioritise-multiple-network-connections This might help you

Comment: If it's a different subnet, which it sounds like it is, Ubuntu should automatically use the correct interface.

Answer (score 1):

OpenSSH `ssh` have a switch `-b`, which allows you to specify to which local IP address it should bind when connecting to the remote host. There is also respective `BindAddress` option which you can store in your `ssh_config`.

Let's say your wireless IP address is `192.168.0.5` and remote host is `remote`, then you can

```
ssh -b 192.168.0.5 remote
```

or store a record in `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host remote
  BindAddress 192.168.0.5
```

to make that working for you.